# Condition не успевает проснуться после notify

Tags: python, многопоточность, race-condition

Изучаю синхронизацию потоков в Python и в первом же примере столкнулся с проблемой. Обычный пример с производителем и покупателем

```
import threading                                                                
from time import sleep·                                                         
                                                                                
products = []                                                                   
condition = threading.Condition()                                               
                                                                                
class Customer(threading.Thread):                                                                                                      
    def run(self):                                                             
        while True:                                                             
            with condition:                                                     
                while len(products) == 0:                                       
                    condition.wait() 
                product = products.pop()                                            
            print('Get product %i ' % product)                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
class Producer(threading.Thread):                                                                                                     
    def run(self):                                                              
        product = 0                                                             
        while True:                                                             
            product += 1                                                                                                        
            with condition:                                                     
                sleep(2) # "make" product                                       
                products.append(product)                                        
                print('Append %i ' % product)                                 
                condition.notify()                                              
                                                                                
customer = Customer()                                                           
producer = Producer()                                                           
customer.start()                                                                
producer.start()
```

Я ожидаю следующую логику работы кода: Customer начинает ждать, и когда Producer вызывает notify и выходит из контекста (with condition), Customer должен проснуться и захватить condition.

Однако этого не происходит. Producer захватывает condition повторно быстрее, и Customer не просыпается.
Если немного помешать ему (Producer) захватывать condition, например добавить sleep(0.001) перед входом в контекст, то все начинает работать логично: Customer успевает проснуться и забрать товар. Таким образом получается состояние гонки, в которой Producer обычно выигрывает. Как грамотно избежать такого состояния? Если я например хочу, чтобы Customer забирал товар сразу после его появления в Producer.

UPD. Исправил опечатку (не было отступа)

```
with condition:                                                     
    condition.wait_for(lambda : len(products) > 0)
 -> product = products.pop()
```

Comment: Так задача всё-таки исходная в чём? Вам нужно, чтобы Customer разгребал всё, что есть в очереди? Мне кажется, тут надо логику немного другую тогда

Comment: @CrazyElf, задачи как таковой нет, просто этот пример много где фигурирует при рассмотрении threading.condition. Но в моем понимании да, Customer должен сразу же разгребать новые объекты, потому что он как раз ждет это условие.

Comment: Так пусть разгребает их в цикле )  Какая-то у вас всё-таки путаница, мне кажется, что-то одно должно быть - либо notify, либо wait_for, а вместе это что-то непонятное получается

Comment: @CrazyElf, как я понял wait_for так же ждет notify и по сути является сокращенной записью для `while not predicate: condition.wait()`. Но теперь я в этом не уверен, поэтому исправлю. Смысл именно в том чтобы ждать notify

Comment: @CrazyElf ну собственно так и есть [wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.wait_for) не работает отдельно от notify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Я ожидаю следующую логику работы кода: Customer начинает ждать, и когда Producer вызывает notify и выходит из контекста (with condition), Customer должен проснуться и захватить condition

Это необоснованное ожидание. `notify` всего лишь выводит поток из состояния блокировки, в которое он ушел после `wait`. Это не значит, что этот поток сразу же гарантированно получит свое время и будет первый в очереди на выполнение. Абсолютно нет, поток `Producer`-а будет работать и успешно захватывать lock ассоциированный с `Condition` пока не кончится его (`Producer`-а) квант времени (раньше это было 100 мс или до IO операции).

Более того, даже когда квант времени кончится, `Consumer` будет на общих основаниях конкурировать со всеми существующими потоками за право выполнятся, и может быть, что это право он получит не скоро (если готовых выполнятся потоков много).

И что еще усложняет тут ситуацию. Представьте, что квант времени `Producer`-а закончился и `Consumer` наконец-то может получить свой квант. Но если в этом момент блокировка захвачена `Producer`-ом (т.е. он находится в блоке with), то `Consumer` обратно уйдет в сон, а `Producer` получит новый квант времени. Это следствие того, что блокировка удерживается дольше чем нужно (см. ниже об этом).

Если вы хотите, чтобы получатель гарантированно обрабатывал сообщения по мере их создания, то вам именно что нужно исскуственно притормозить продюсера. Это называется [backpressure](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/glossary#Back-Pressure) - а именно, возможность `Consumer`-у просигнализировать `Producer`-у, что обработка не успевает за генерацией.

Есть много способов как это сделать. Можно смотреть на длину очереди, если  длинная (или даже не пустая), то ждать пока это не изменится. Для этого может понадобиться отдельный `Event` или `Condition`, только уже в другую сторону - от `Consumer`-а к `Producer`-у.

И еще одно замечание. В данном примере `condition` используется для двух вещей:

1. синхронизации доступа к `products` из разных потоков
2. для отсылки уведомления

Удерживать блокировку ассоциированную с `condition` нужно только, когда идет модификация или чтение `products` и посылка уведомления. В другое время это только будет тормозить `Consumer`-a без необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение. Я предполагал, что Customer после пробуждения состоит в равных правах в борьбе за лок кондишена, но мне почему то это показалось очень нелогичным. Не могли вы намекнуть, как называются эти способы?

Comment: Не понял вопрос про `способы`. Что имеете ввиду?

Comment: Вы пишете что есть много способов притормозить продьюсера. Ну то есть кроме банального sleep, есть ли какой грамотный способ, который гарантировано позволит Customer у взять condition первым. Возможно у них есть какое то общее название

Comment: добавил. В общем это называется backpressure.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле тут гонки нет, Customer просыпается столько же раз, сколько было notify. Когда выплюнет результат зависит похоже от того в каком треде сейчас GIL.

Исправить можно если захватывать кондишн только в момент передачи результата:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

products = []
condition = threading.Condition()

from queue import Queue

q = Queue()

class Customer(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            with condition:
                condition.wait_for(lambda : len(products) > 0)
                product = products.pop()
            q.put('Get product %i ' % product)


class Producer(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        product = 0
        while True:
            product += 1
            sleep(2) # "make" product
            with condition:
                products.append(product)
                q.put('Append %i ' % product)
                condition.notify()

customer = Customer()
producer = Producer()
customer.start()
producer.start()


while True:
    print(q.get())
```

Состояние под with синхронизируется и похоже не дает прыгать GIL.

Comment: Просыпаться то он просыпается, но вот захватить condition он не успевает, потому что Producer захватывает его раньше. Иногда (редко) Customer успевает раньше и тогда он выдергивает product из списка. Разве это не гонка? А так почти всегда Producer первый захватывает и список products только растет.
"Исправить можно если захватывать кондишн только в момент передачи результата:" я про это написал в вопросе, если вставить sleep(0.001) то таким образом мы затормозим Producer и Customer будет захватывать condition первым. Но это не решение на мой взгляд.

Comment: успевает, но не всегда. кондишн не должен захватываться во время работы так как он блокирует внутренний мутекс.

Answer (score -1):

Вы неправильно используете `condition`. Объект `Condition` является просто усовершенствованным вариантом объекта `Event`. Он тоже работает как коммуникатор между потоками и может применяться для уведомления `notify()` других потоков об изменении состояния программы. Например, его можно использовать для сигнализации доступности ресурса. Другие потоки также должны получать условие `acquire()` (и, следовательно, связанное с ним блокирование) до ожидания `wait()` для удовлетворения условия. Кроме того, поток должен освободить `release()` по условию `Condition` после завершения связанных с ним действий, так что другие потоки могут получить условие для своих целей.
Ваш код будет работать, если использовать указанное выше:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

products = []
condition = threading.Condition()


class Customer(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            condition.acquire()
            condition.wait()                
            product = products.pop()
            print('Get product %i ' % product)
            condition.release()


class Producer(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        product = 0
        while True:
            product += 1
            sleep(2)  # "make" product
            condition.acquire()
            products.append(product)
            condition.notify()
            print('Append %i ' % product)
            condition.release()


customer = Customer()
producer = Producer()
customer.start()
producer.start()
```

Вывод:

```
Append 1 
Get product 1 
Append 2 
Get product 2 
Append 3 
Get product 3
```

Comment: перечитайте мой вопрос и мой комментарий к первому ответу. Вы переместили sleep перед acquire. Я хочу создавать продукт после acquire. Вместо явного использования acquire я использую менеджер контекста. Где я неправильно использую condition?  Вы скопировали описание condtion [отсюда](https://nuancesprog.ru/p/202/) только что это объясняет?

Comment: Неправильно, потому что сначала генерируется элемент, потом блокируется поток, потом добавляется элемент в список, потом отсылается уведомление о доступности новых данных и поток разблокируется

Comment: Ну так у меня так и есть, только когда генерировать элемент вопрос неоднозначный, может мне надо генерировать элемент как раз после блокировки.

Comment: Я не углублялся в тему, но сама генерация элемента всегда вынесена за блокировку потока во всех примерах.

Comment: Делать действие, когда блокировка захвачена и не нужна, это плохо. Приводит как раз к проблемам, что `Consumer` мог бы прочитать и обработать, но ждет. `condition` в этом примере нужен для двух вещей: 1. защиты списка от конкурентного доступа 2. для нотификации. Держать блокировку нужно только в момент модификации `products` и отсылки нотификации.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, пример искусственный, но ведь в принципе при создании элемента тоже может требоваться блокировка, если в этот момент используются общие ресурсы

Comment: @razrabochka Для другого разделяемого ресурса используйте отдельную блокировку. Какой смысл чтобы создание product и его обработка comsumer-ом блокировали друг друга?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, согласен никакого. Но тут смысл ситуации ведь именно в том чтобы блокировка происходила как можно быстрее, именно в этом случае такая ситуация и возникает

Comment: Не понимаю, что имеется ввиду под `чтобы блокировка происходила как можно быстрее`.

Comment: Имею в виду, что такая ситуация возникает, когда в Producer condition блокируется  сразу после `while True:`. Если поставить `sleep` перед блокировкой то описываемой ситуации не возникнет. Ну а  мне естественно важно было понять эту ситуацию, а не просто заставить работать этот искусственный пример. Но то что блокируемая область должна быть как можно меньше я понял.